# Lua Metatables - calling functions with colon syntax

Tags: lua, self, metatable

I have the following problem, somebody can help me?

```
comp = {}
comp.__index = function(obj,val)
  if val == "insert" then
    return rawget(obj,"gr")["insert"]
  end
  return rawget(obj, val)
end

comp.new = function() 
  local ret = {} 
  setmetatable(ret, comp) 
  ret.gr = display.newGroup()
  return ret
end
local pru = comp.new()
```

```
pru.gr:insert(display.newImage("wakatuBlue.png"))
```

This line works, but I don't want to access the insert method using the `gr` property, I want to call the insert method directly and the metatable `__index` function does the work

```
pru:insert(display.newImage("wakatuBlue.png"))
```

This line doesn't work and I get this error: `"bad argument #-2 to 'insert' (Proxy expected, got nil)"`, but this is the way that I'm looking to use

Comment: You should have mentioned in your description that the code is for Corona SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
comp = {}
comp.__index = function(obj,val)
  if val == "insert" then
    return rawget(obj,"gr"):insert(val)
  end
  return rawget(obj, val)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

__index works just fine; it's because your last call is interpreted as:

```
pru.insert(pru, display.newImage("wakatuBlue.png"))
```

whereas you want/need it to be:

```
pru.insert(pru.gr, display.newImage("wakatuBlue.png"))
```

You either need to call it like this or explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I wonder why the error is that argument #-2 is nil, when it should be `pru` which isn't nil (just not a Proxy).

Comment: It's because Corona detects Proxy as a table with a field `_proxy` that points to some userdata. If you add `_proxy = {}` to `pru`, you will get a different error ("Proxy expected, got table").